# Digits available for angular 2 app?

Tags: angular, twitter-digits

How can we implement Digits by Twitter in Angular 2 App?

I tried to use Javascript version, by including SDK JS file in index.html page 
And adding Javascript code into the ngAfterViewInit method.

Like  this code ..

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    constructor() { }

    onLogin(loginResponse) {
        // Send headers to your server and validate user by calling Digits’ API
        let oAuthHeaders = loginResponse.oauth_echo_headers;
        let verifyData = {
            authHeader: oAuthHeaders['X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization'],
            apiUrl: oAuthHeaders['X-Auth-Service-Provider']
        };
        console.log('verifyData', verifyData);
        //   $.post('/verify', verifyData)
        //     .done(function(){ window.reload(); });
    }

    onLoginFailure(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        document.getElementById('digits-sdk').onload = function () {
            Digits.init({ consumerKey: 'yourConsumerKey' });
        };

        Digits.embed({
            container: '.my-digits-container',
            theme: {
                accent: '315B7F',       /* Buttons & Links */
                background: '002747',   /* Transparent by defaul */
                label: 'FFF',           /* Titles and text */
                border: '324F67'        /* Input fields borders */
            }
        })
            .done(this.onLogin) /*handle the response*/
            .fail(this.onLoginFailure);
    }
}
```

But but I am getting error as "Digits"  is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You should give digits sdk cdn url in your index.html for initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You should give digits sdk cdn url in your index.html for initialization for digits.